# Object name instead of OID in GoSNMP

Tags: go, snmp, net-snmp, gosnmp

Is it possible to return Object name instead of OID using [gosnmp](https://godoc.org/github.com/soniah/gosnmp)

For eg:

Instead of

```
    ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.1.1": {
        "type": "2",
        "val": "1"
    },
```

How can i get:

```
    "hrStorageIndex": {
        "type": "2",
        "val": "1"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - use [MIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base)s. GoSNMP doesn't have MIB support, but you can use the idea from https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp/issues/57